# Getting an indent error with python 3 printing

Tags: python

this is ridiculous that I can't figure out why this isn't working...

```
def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.

    Creates a Gmail API service object and outputs a list of label names
    of the user's Gmail account.
    """

    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    results = ListThreadsMatchingQuery(service, EMAIL_LOGIN, 'email@gmail.com') ## searching based on email
    print(len(results))
```

I get the error:

```
$ python quickstart1.py 
  File "quickstart1.py", line 155
    print(len(results))
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: I suggest copy pasting this code, because this code does not raise that error.

Comment: I did copy/paste it!

Comment: I'm saying copy the code in this question back to your editor and run it. Because I copy pasted that and I can't re-produce your problem.

Comment: Same thing, I don't get an error, but when I run the file, I do....

Comment: Is it possible you have mixed tabs and spaces? maybe just delete the code in the file and replace it with the code from here?

Comment: "Same thing, I don't get an error, but when I run the file, I do" This is because Stack Overflow converts tabs to spaces in formatted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use both 4 spaces and tab indent in Python code. Next time,  set your editor to use 4-space indents.

Comment: @MorganAllen: Also, check whether you're really on Python 3. Python 3 would probably have given you a different, more informative error.

Comment: @user2357112 [Not always, unfortunately, not even in 2023](https://discuss.python.org/t/_/40673).